# Compiling Pandoc Haskell script: Could not find module `Text.Pandoc.JSON'

Tags: pandoc, haskell

I am trying to use a canned example from [Pandoc's scripting page](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html), but I don't understand enough Haskell to  make this work. Here's the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
-- includes.hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

doInclude :: Block -> IO Block
doInclude cb@(CodeBlock (id, classes, namevals) contents) =
  case lookup "include" namevals of
       Just f     -> return . (CodeBlock (id, classes, namevals)) =<< readFile f
       Nothing    -> return cb
doInclude x = return x

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter doInclude
```

I saved this as `includes.hs`. To use it as a Panodc filter I need to compile it, so I ran `ghc --make include.hs`, but got the following error.

```
C:\Users\richa_000\Dropbox\CV>ghc --make includes.hs

includes.hs:3:8:
    Could not find module `Text.Pandoc.JSON'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Isn't `Text.PANDOC.JSON` installed with Pandoc? I can't find any information on how to install package. Am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer in this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472828/unable-to-compile-haskell-program-couldnt-match-errors). I need to add the Pandoc libraries *to Haskell*.

Here's the command

```
cabal install pandoc
```

I had to update cabal first.

Comment: You can also use Stack: `stack install pandoc`